# How can I write a Windows (NTFS) .img file to a partition and add it to grub?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, grub, linux-kvm

I'm trying some crazy stuff here. First, I had a VirtualBox machine with Windows XP installed, using .vdi format. Then I exported the image to a OVA, extracted the .vmdk and converted it to a raw .img file. Then I've created a new VM into KVM via virt-manager, loaded this image as a hard disk and got it running.

Now, I'm trying to copy this entire image to a disk partition, via `dd`, and boot the first NTFS partition inside this image on boot, via `grub`. So far, i've already dd'ed the first partition inside the image (the actual NTFS partition) and it was recognized both by gParted as NTFS and grub as a Windows install, but I can't boot it. So I've tried to copy the entire image, including the partition table, boot sector and stuff, to this `/dev/sda4` physical partition. Now the image is booting via KVM, but I can't find a way to add it to Grub. I'm trying to find a way to do it via loop mounting, I just have no idea on how config grub to mount/map/boot this image and access the first (NTFS) partition inside it.

What I want to do:

```
- Turn my XP image into a valid physical installation to dual boot
- Keep the VM running from this disk partition
```

This way, if possible, I'll use the VM on Ubuntu, or boot it on grub.

For clarification, the commands I used:

```
$ sudo su

# mounts the entire image
$ losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/WindowsXP.img
$ fdisk -l /dev/loop0

> Device        Boot    Start   End         Blocks      Id  System
> /dev/loop0p1  *       63      31439204    15719571    7   HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

# mounts the first NTFS partition inside image (offset 63*512)
$ losetup /dev/loop1 -o 32256 /dev/loop0
```

At this point, I have both NTFS partition on `/dev/loop1` and the full disk (with MBR) on `/dev/loop0`. Then:

```
# copied the entire image to /dev/sda4. This is not recognized by GRUB, 
# therefore it must be loopmounted before booted via grub config somehow
$ dd if=/dev/loop0 of=/dev/sda4 bs=10m

# copied the NTFS virtual partition to physical one
# GRUB should recognize and boot it, since is a valid XP install, however it misses the partition table,
# so the virtual machine won't be able to boot it.
$ dd if /dev/loop1 of=/dev/sda4 bs=10m
```

As an alternative, I thought about a second disk image attached to VM, only with GRUB and minimal info to boot this partition.
This way, I could keep the NTFS partition on `/dev/sda4` to grub as a dual boot, and boot from a second tiny image on KVM.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is more of a suggestion, not a well-informed answer.

Since you seem to be able to copy the Windows partition to a legitimate physical partition (`/dev/sda4`) why don't you just boot `/dev/sda` in a virtual machine? You could then boot into the Windows partition by choosing the Windows option in GRUB. It appears this sort of setup has been done before: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=68216

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know that I could boot `/dev/sda` directly via `qemu /dev/sda`. That will make my tests a lot easier. 
I wanted to boot XP as a dual-boot, to enable direct access to hardware, and play some games, without losing the ability to run it inside a VM. I think the best solution is a fresh install of XP into  `/dev/sda4` and reinstall grub to enable the dual boot option. I'll try it.